# PHP Login Using password_hash

Tags: php, authentication, crypt, password-hash

The following code does not work:

Login Page:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='{$name}'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if(password_verify($pass, $row['pass'])){
                $_SESSION['logged'] = true; 
                $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
                $_SESSION['pass'] = $row['pass'];
                //header('Location: index.php');
                echo "Workded";
            } else {
                echo "Crypt Not Matching";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code used to insert into database:

```
if (empty($e1)) {
        $password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        if ($mysqli->query("INSERT into users (name, pass, email, gamertag, psnid, youtube, fbauth) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$xbox', '$psn', '$youtube', '$fbid')")) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['logged'] = true; 
            $_SESSION['name'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $password;
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
    }
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's not wroking? What error are you getting? WHat do you get and what do you expected to get?

Comment: No errors, just trying to validate the login. Whereas to match the login password with the one stored in database to initialize the session and log the user in.

Answer (score 0):

1 - debug the $_POST var and check if its being passed correctly from the HTTP POST request

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

2 - debug the result of the database, in the foreach loop, and check if you're retrieving the information from the db correctly

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

3 - test if password_hash and password_verify are working correctly.

```
$pwd = 'some_password';
$hash = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
var_dump(password_verify($pwd, $hash);
```